# Recording and playing video

Tags: ios, flutter

In my current flutter project i need to record video, modified it and then show to user.
The problem is that in the iOS (14.2) the recorded video/modified can not be shown by video player, unfortunately there is no error from iOS (tested on physical devices).

Libraries and versions:

```
video_player: 1.0.1
flick_video_player: ^0.1.1
camera: ^0.5.8+17
flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.3.0
```

The reason why i do not use newest version of camera is that it is bugged and for certain number of devices there is no way to show even the preview.

Code:

1. Camera initialization

```dart
  Future<void> _initCamera() async {
     final cameras = await availableCameras();
     final camera = cameras.firstWhereOrNull(
       (element) => element.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back,
      );

    _controller = CameraController(
      camera,
      resolutionTarget,
      enableAudio: false,
    );

    await _controller.initialize();
    await _controller.prepareForVideoRecording();

    //Show the preview
    setState(() {});
  }
```

2. Recording video

```html
  Future<void> startVideoRecording() async {
    _videoPath = await generatePath(PathExtension.mp4);
    await _controller.startVideoRecording(_videoPath);
  }

  Future<String> stopVideoRecording() async{
    await _controller.stopVideoRecording();
    return _videoPath;
  }
```

3. Showing recorded video

```html
  void _createFlickManager(File videoFile) {
    final videoController = VideoPlayerController.file(videoFile);
    _flickManager = FlickManager(
      videoPlayerController: videoController,
    );
  }
  
  Widget _buildVideoPreview(){
    return FlickVideoPlayer(
              flickManager: _flickManager,
              flickVideoWithControls:
                  FlickVideoWithControls(controls: Container()),
            );
  }
```

Summary:

- the camera preview is showing properly,
- the recording video file has size and does not throw any exception,
- black screen when trying to show video using FlickVideoPlayer or just VideoPlayer,
- converted video to mp4/mov by ffmpeg still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in iOS 14.2 there is problem with paths that contains spaces, as i used `DateTime.now()`
to generate unique file name and that was reason of the problem. Changing it to `DateTime.now().millisecond` solved it.